# Question on Eclipse .project file builders

Tags: java, eclipse, project

Could anyone explain a bit on the the buildCommand section in a eclipse .project file. I have currently got following buildCommands for a local eclipse .project file:

```
org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder; 

org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder; 

org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder; 

org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder;
```

My questions are:

1. What are those builders for?
2. When are they triggered? Are they triggered always in this order or eclipse is smart enough to know which builder to select for the current build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are incremental builders declared by plug-ins using the `org.eclipse.core.resources.builders` extension point.

They are called whenever resources are changed in the project. The builder is told which resources have changed so it can decide if it needs to do anything. The builders are also called when you do a full build. The builder is told which type of build is being performed.

Exactly what each builder does would require looking at the builder code. `org.eclipse.jdt.xxxx` builders are part of the Java Development Tools. `org.eclipse.wst.xxx` are part of the web tools.

The 'Builders' page in the project Properties also lists these builders with a descriptive name which may help to identify what each one does. You can also disable them individually. It is also possible to add your own builders.

The Eclipse 'Platform Plug-in Development Guide' in the Eclipse help has lots more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the enlightening explanation!

Comment: I have a number of related maven projects which were causing an endless loop of builds. Removing the `maven2Builder` stopped that loop. I haven't yet noticed any negative side-effects. I'm guessing it does a kind of `Maven->Update project...`action which I seem to have to do anyway